Inkscape giving import TIFF errors on 24.04
When I try to import a tiff into Inkscape I get the following error:
Failed to load the requested file /run/user/1000/doc/6ec7e431
Enchantments3dLIGHTENED.tif

The actual path to the file is in a home folder actually and not the path shown above.
After searching around the internet I found that tiff import errors might be cause by a missing library so I installed
sudo apt-get install libtiff-dev

This did not stop the error.
I uninstalled inkscape (which I initially installed with sudo apt install inkscape).  I removed inkscape, did an autoremove, did an update, then installed via snap install inkscape.
This did not solve the problem.
If I start Inkscape via the terminal, then try to import the TIFF I get the following message:
(org.inkscape.Inkscape:6110): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 08:14:59.027: Error creating IO channel for /proc/self/mountinfo: Permission denied (g-file-error-quark, 2)
Pixbuf::create_from_file: Unrecognized image file format
   (/run/user/1000/doc/6ec7e431/Enchantments3D2LIGHTENED.tif)
GdkPixbuf loader failed

** (org.inkscape.Inkscape:6110): WARNING **: 08:15:13.317: atk-bridge: get_device_events_reply: unknown signature

(org.inkscape.Inkscape:6110): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: 08:15:21.020: Error creating IO channel for /proc/self/mountinfo: Permission denied (g-file-error-quark, 2)
Pixbuf::create_from_file: Unrecognized image file format
   (/run/user/1000/doc/39aa00cc/Enchantments3D2LIGHTENED.tif)
GdkPixbuf loader failed

I should note the the TIFF opens fine in other software like the default image viewer and GIMP.
I will not repeat the steps above but I did try using the stump version of inkscape and that made no difference to the error.
How do I fix Inkscape to work with my TIFF import?
Update:  The import will happen with a PNG.
